# multiple serverside datatable with switch button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have page that have 3 tables that using datatables, the problem is datatables cant handle more than 1 tables and I already searching the solution and what I get is using customized SSP Datatables : [here](https://github.com/emran/ssp)

but, what I want to ask is if there is more simple approach from this problem ?

-this is slice of page that showing 3 switchable server-side table based on buttons

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class ="row">
   <div class ="text-center alert col-md-12">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#table_assall" data-toggle="tab">All Assets List</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#table_asborrow" data-toggle="tab">Used Assets</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#table_asbroken" data-toggle="tab">Damaged Assets</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div id="table_assall" class="tab-pane fade active in">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="">
            *thead source code*
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="table_asborrow" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="">
            *thead source code*
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="table_asbroken" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="">
            *thead source code*
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

-this is JS Files that trigger show table query

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
        $('table.display').DataTable({
            lengthChange: true,
            info: false,
            fixedHeader: true,
            select: true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "serverSide": true,         
            "ajax":{
                url :"tableresponses.php", // json datasource
                type: "post",  // type of method  , by default would be get
                    error: function(){  // error handling code
                    $("#astab_processing").css("display","none");
                    }
            }
        });   
});
```

so is it posible to change the ajax url based on button click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the `url` based on your button `click`, my suggestion would be to use a **global variable** and write `click event` to your `button` and change the value of global variable.

**Ex**

```
<div class ="text-center alert col-md-12">
      <a class="btn btn-primary changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses.php" href="#table_assall" data-toggle="tab">All Assets List</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses1.php" href="#table_asborrow" data-toggle="tab">Used Assets</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses2.php" href="#table_asbroken" data-toggle="tab">Damaged Assets</a>
</div>
```

Note that an extra class named `changeTable` and a extra `html5` attribute, `data-ajax` has been added to your buttons.

Now declare a global variable and write `click event` for your buttons.

```
var _ajaxURL="";//you can initialize this global variable with some default value.

$('.changeTable').on('click',function(){
    _ajaxURL=$(this).attr('data-ajax');
});
```

Now, the `ajax` part of `dataTable` would look like

```
"ajax":{
    url :_ajaxURL, // json datasource
    type: "post",  // type of method  , by default would be get
    error: function(){  // error handling code
        $("#astab_processing").css("display","none");
    }
}
```

Let me know if you face any issues on this.

Comment: code dont show any error, but my table stuck at "processing" (loading state before showing the table)

Comment: the table showing now, but the button didn't trigger the data-ajax, I check in browser console it didnt post the data..

Comment: Are those buttons added dynamically?

Comment: sry, I didnt understand what you mean on buttons added dynamically

Comment: As in, these buttons are added after html page load? anywhere in between after the page is loaded completely?

Comment: ok..  can you `console.log(_ajaxURL)` after `_ajaxURL=$(this).attr('data-ajax');` and check if that event is triggered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150699/discussion-between-gusti-aldi-and-guruprasad-rao).